# Leap status : Not synchronised

Tags: networking, server

I am running `chronyc tracking` on the workstation computer as a client and the robot's computer as a server.

if I run it when ethernet connect to AP (wifi device), sometimes `Reference ID` is the same and sometimes not.

what is the reason in this case?

I usually run it when ethernet does not connect to AP (wifi device).

`In this case,
on the robot:

```
Reference ID    : 127.127.1.1 ()
Stratum         : 8
Ref time (UTC)  : Tue Nov 23 08:40:29 2021
System time     : 0.000000001 seconds fast of NTP time
Last offset     : +0.000000000 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.000000000 seconds
Frequency       : 13.747 ppm fast
Residual freq   : +0.000 ppm
Skew            : 0.000 ppm
Root delay      : 0.000000 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.000001 seconds
Update interval : 0.0 seconds
Leap status     : Not synchronised
```

on the workstation:

```
Reference ID    : <IP robot> (RIA-E100)
Stratum         : 9
Ref time (UTC)  : Tue Nov 23 08:39:16 2021
System time     : 0.000001817 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : -0.001256107 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.001256107 seconds
Frequency       : 475.389 ppm fast
Residual freq   : -548.964 ppm
Skew            : 50.148 ppm
Root delay      : 0.002493 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.008189 seconds
Update interval : 1.9 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

my question is, can I sync them using IP AP static?